# vscode can't find python's requests library

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-line, path, python-requests

I've downloaded the requests library with pip install, and I can use it on my command line, and with python's IDLE but not in vscode.

Here is the code from vsc:

```
import requests

requests.__version__
```

Here is the error thrown out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abdourahman/Desktop/webscrape/igscrape.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

When run on cmd & IDLE it runs as intended:

```
Python 3.7.4 (v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 14:54:52)[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests 
>>> 
>>> requests.__version__
'2.23.0'
```

To reiterate I'd like figure out to access external libraries in my ide. I've run into the same problem with `vscode` & `atom`, and with the bs4 library along with requests.

Comment: vscode isn't using the same python version that you're testing.

Comment: checked the vscode json settings and "which python3" on my terminal and they both have the same path. /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial & https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: thanks, this documentation helped me figure out what I was doing wrong

Comment: You can post an answer and mark it correct and it will help future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was the Code Runner extension I was running source code in vscode out of. Turned it off and it defaulted to running python out of the terminal in vscode which solved the problem of not being able to find the modules.

Comment: how do you fixed the issue I have the same issue